# Вёрстка инпута для загрузки файла без JS

Tags: css, вёрстка, input

Всем привет,

Подскажите, можно ли сверстать такой инпут как на скриншоте без применения JS, на чистом HTML и CSS? И если да, то какой должна быть его html-структура, чтобы я мог отдельно стилизовать кнопку "загрузить", кнопку с крестиком и строку с именем файла? Естественно, всё это должно ещё и работать (кнопка - загружать файл, крестик - удалять, название - обновляться).

[image: скриншот]

Создание обычного <инпут тип="файл"> возвращает монолитную конструкцию из кнопки и имени файла, которую непонятно как стилизовать, да и кнопки удаления нет. Если же без JS никак не обойтись, то также прошу подсказать способы реализации задачи.

Comment: Конструкцию <label for=""> не пробовали использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите иметь функционал кнопки и поля типа `DropZone` и при этом строить своё представление этого элемента формы, то делается следующим образом. Сам элементу устанавливаем видимость в 0, растягиваем элемент на всю площадь `DropZone` и ставим `z-index` выше своего представление. То есть, своё представление строите непосредственно под `<input>`.

Получается вроде такого:

```
input[type=file]{
   opacity:0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Но ваш функционал вряд ли осуществим на чистом CSS. Если вы используете на вашем сайте jQuery, вам наверняка понравится [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/).

Если вы предпочитаете легковесные решения, то вот вам несколько ссылок на простенькие скрипты:

- https://github.com/pb03/input-file
- https://github.com/nifte/better-file-input
- https://github.com/lifenautjoe/droppable
- https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/
- https://github.com/promosis/file-upload-with-preview